# Setting strokeCap or software layer make the line disappear

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm having simple custom view, which should effectively work as a progressbar.
I'd like to draw it with rounded corners, but that's seems to be not working for me..Below is whole code..In this state it gets drawn correctly, but without rounded corners. Once I set the strokeCap, or the layerType, the view gets effectively blank. Does anybody know why? And how to solve my issue?

EDIT: another interesting point is that eventhough drawLine works without strokeCap, drawPath does not draw any content at all. I have been drawing to canvas many times without ever having such weird issues..damn
EDIT 2: Path too large to be rendered into a texture - this am I getting while trying to render it with drawPath (but its definitely smaller then the maxWidth/height - the view is about 32x10dips)

```
public class CustomViewPagerIndicator extends View {

Paint mBgPaint;
Paint mFgPaing;
private int mMax;
private int mProgress;

public CustomViewPagerIndicator(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public CustomViewPagerIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomViewPagerIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mMax = 1;
//  setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    mBgPaint = new Paint();
    mBgPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_2_translucent));
    mBgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBgPaint.setStrokeWidth(R.dimen.grid_1);
//  mBgPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mBgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    mFgPaing = new Paint();
    mFgPaing.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_1));
    mFgPaing.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mFgPaing.setStrokeWidth(R.dimen.grid_1);
//  mFgPaing.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mFgPaing.setAntiAlias(true);
}


public void setMax(int max){
    mMax = max;
};

public int getMax() {
    return mMax;
}

public void setProgress(int progress){
    mProgress = progress;
    invalidate();
}

public int getProgress() {
    return mProgress;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float step = getMeasuredWidth()/mMax;

    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth(), getMeasuredHeight()/2, mBgPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight()/2, step*mProgress, getMeasuredHeight()/2, mFgPaing);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the rounded corners not showing up is they are drawn off the edge of the canvas.  You draw the line from one edge of the canvas to the other. `drawLine` draws the line at the coordinates given and then adds the caps.  In your case, there is no room left on the canvas.  You need to leave room for the caps by starting and ending drawing one half of your stroke length from the edges to leave room for the caps. See the example below.  I have STROKE_SIZE as constant, but you probably want to load it with [`getDimension()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension%28int%29) on `R.dimen.grid_1`.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float step = (canvas.getWidth()-STROKE_SIZE/2)/(float)mMax;

    canvas.drawLine(STROKE_SIZE/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth()-STROKE_SIZE/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, mBgPaint);
    if(mProgress != 0) {
        canvas.drawLine(STROKE_SIZE / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, step * mProgress, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, mFgPaing);
    }
}
```

Comment: albeit it's very good point (I scratched my had and spotted this silly fact the other day) - it doesn't help. Once I set those caps (to round), the line disappears and once I try to draw it with drawPath instead of drawLine it dissapears as well, plus I got the message, that the path is way too large to be rendered into bitmap.:/

Comment: that message on drawPath should be fixed by uncommenting the line `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`  I used the code above and got exactly the correct behavior you are looking for, so I am out of ideas.